# windows forms load report failed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

I am developing a Windows Form application using Visual Studio 2010 and framework 4.0.   I have a number of reports that this application will use.

My solution is divided up into folders so that I can keep my files organized.   I have a process in one folder that is trying to load the Crystal Report located in another folder.

When I try to load the report file, I get an error "Load Report Failed".   A Google search says it either cannot find the file or the folder does not have permission to access it.   Since this is a WinForms application,  I do not think the permissions have anything to do with the error since this application and all its folders are included in the overall assembly.  I have tried - in debug mode - to use difference file naming to include the folder using just about every combination I can think of but to no avail.

I cannot see why the error occurs.  Any clues?

```
        Dim rpt As New ReportDocument
        With rpt
            .Load("Form1500_0212.rpt")
            .SetParameterValue(0, bID)
            .SetParameterValue(1, ProviderID)
            .VerifyDatabase()

        End With
        Dim frm As New frmViewReport()
        frm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also discovered that you need to change the property for "Copy to Output Directory" needs to be set to "Copy Always" so that the report definition is available in the executable path.  Now my code works with this

```
 With rpt
    .Load(Application.StartupPath + "\Form1500_0212.rpt")
    .SetParameterValue(0, bID)
    .SetParameterValue(1, ProviderID)
 End With
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of possibilities why this is happening..

first, try to specify the full filepath for this line of code

```
.Load("fullfilepath") 
'e.g., "C:\EmailSys-Phase2\Code\EmailSystem1\xtalReport.rpt"
```

second, have you installed the runtimes for crystal reports? You can get it [here](http://global.sap.com/campaign/ne/free_trial/crystal_reports_visual_studio/wty_int_crvs.epx)

third, have you tried adding this on your `app.config` file?

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

fourth, try checking if your `target framework` is set to `.NET Framework 4.0` **AND NOT** `.NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile`  (I think you're okay with this step already)

Comment: I tried the full path and it does not throw the error but if I include the full path in my code then when the program is packaged and distributed to a server, that path will not longer be valid.   So how should I handle it then?

The other three points you mention are all in place on my development PC and were the first things I checked.

Comment: when you make an installer/deploy your program, you have to add the crystal report files (rpt) to the installer project so that when you install, the rpt files will always be on the application directory - regardless of the PC you wish to install your app. Then you can use `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory() & "reportname.rpt"` to get the full path.